# Missing some MFC headers

Tags: visual-studio-2012, mfc

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate so the MFC library should be included, but I find that I'm missing some header files in the `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\atlmfc\include` directory, specifically `afxwin.h`, `afxtempl.h`, and `afxext.h`.

Other than seeing if reinstalling will work, how can I acquire these files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized on a recent installation I forgot to include installation of the MFC files